# Why is this graphics object not painting? (What am i doing wrong?)

Tags: java, swing, graphics, drag-and-drop

So I am writing a program in Java, and one of the important things it needs to be able to do is render multiple objects onto the screen that can be dragged and dropped by the user. I have made a class (pasted below), but when I try to initialise one with

```
new DragNode();
```

it doesn't work.
Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?
Thanks,
Sam

```
public static class DragNode extends JLabel{
    public static final long serialVersionUID=155L;

    public class MA extends MouseAdapter{
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            preX = rect.x - e.getX();
            preY = rect.y - e.getY();

            if (rect.contains(e.getX(), e.getY())) {
                updateLocation(e);
                System.out.println("Mouse pressed on rectangle");
            } else {
                pressOut = true;
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
            if (!pressOut) {
                updateLocation(e);
            } else {
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
            if (rect.contains(e.getX(), e.getY())) {
                updateLocation(e);
            } else {
                pressOut = false;
            }
        }
        public void updateLocation(MouseEvent e) {
            rect.setLocation(preX + e.getX(), preY + e.getY());
            checkRect();

            repaint();
        }
    }

    public int x,y;
    Rectangle rect,area;
    int preX,preY;
    boolean firstTime=true;
    boolean pressOut=false;
    private Dimension dim=getGraphPanelSize();
    private Image Node_Sprite;

    public DragNode(){
        init();
    }
    public DragNode(int x,int y){
        this.x=x;
        this.y=y;
        init();
    }
    public void init(){
        //setBackground(Color.GRAY);
        setOpaque(false);
        addMouseMotionListener(new MA());
        addMouseListener(new MA());
        rect = new Rectangle(x, y, 50, 50);
        area=new Rectangle(dim);
        try{
        Node_Sprite=ImageIO.read(new File("Node_Sprite.png"));
        }catch(IOException ioe){}
    }
    boolean checkRect() {
        if (area == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (area.contains(rect.x, rect.y, rect.getWidth(), rect.getHeight())) {
            return true;
        }
        int new_x = rect.x;
        int new_y = rect.y;
        if ((rect.x + rect.getWidth()) > area.getWidth()) {
            new_x = (int) area.getWidth() - (int) (rect.getWidth() - 1);
        }
        if (rect.x < 0) {
            new_x = -1;
        }
        if ((rect.y + rect.getHeight()) > area.getHeight()) {
            new_y = (int) area.getHeight() - (int) (rect.getHeight() - 1);
        }
        if (rect.y < 0) {
            new_y = -1;
        }
        rect.setLocation(new_x, new_y);
        return false;
    }
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING,
                RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);

        if (firstTime) {
            rect.setLocation(x,y);
            firstTime = false;
        }
        g2d.setColor(new Color(0,0,0,0));
        g2d.drawImage(Node_Sprite, rect.x,rect.y,50,50,null);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When I replace the code for drawing the rectangle with

```
    g2d.setColor(Color.red);
    g2d.fillRect( rect.x, rect.y, 50, 50);
    // g2d.drawImage(Node_Sprite, rect.x, rect.y, 50, 50, null);
```

It is drawn and can be dragged in the x-direction. So there might be something wrong with your image (does it exist in the specified folder?). I expected the dragging to be in both directions, so there might be an issue there as well for the y-direction.

**EDIT:** Ok, I tried it with an image as well, works well. I also saw that your "borders" 'dim' are set very narrow, so I increased them to 300/300 so I can drag around my image in both axis.

[image: It's a me, Mario!]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

import net.miginfocom.swing.MigLayout;

public class DragNode extends JLabel {
    public static final long serialVersionUID = 155L;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JLabel node = new DragNode();
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("blupp");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new MigLayout(""));
        frame.getContentPane().add(node, "grow, push");
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setSize(new Dimension(500, 300));
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public class MA extends MouseAdapter {
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            preX = rect.x - e.getX();
            preY = rect.y - e.getY();

            if (rect.contains(e.getX(), e.getY())) {
                updateLocation(e);
                System.out.println("Mouse pressed on rectangle");
            } else {
                pressOut = true;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
            if (!pressOut) {
                updateLocation(e);
            } else {}
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
            if (rect.contains(e.getX(), e.getY())) {
                updateLocation(e);
            } else {
                pressOut = false;
            }
        }

        public void updateLocation(MouseEvent e) {
            rect.setLocation(preX + e.getX(), preY + e.getY());
            checkRect();

            repaint();
        }
    }

    public int x, y;
    Rectangle rect, area;
    int preX, preY;
    boolean firstTime = true;
    boolean pressOut = false; 
    private Dimension dim = new Dimension(300, 300);
    private Image Node_Sprite;

    public DragNode() {
        init();
    }

    public DragNode(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        init();
    }

    public void init() {
        //setBackground(Color.GRAY);
        setOpaque(false);
        addMouseMotionListener(new MA());
        addMouseListener(new MA());
        rect = new Rectangle(x, y, 50, 50);
        area = new Rectangle(dim);
        try {
            Node_Sprite = ImageIO.read(new File("Node_Sprite.png"));
        } catch (IOException ioe) {}
    }

    boolean checkRect() {
        if (area == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (area.contains(rect.x, rect.y, rect.getWidth(), rect.getHeight())) {
            return true;
        }
        int new_x = rect.x;
        int new_y = rect.y;
        if ((rect.x + rect.getWidth()) > area.getWidth()) {
            new_x = (int) area.getWidth() - (int) (rect.getWidth() - 1);
        }
        if (rect.x < 0) {
            new_x = -1;
        }
        if ((rect.y + rect.getHeight()) > area.getHeight()) {
            new_y = (int) area.getHeight() - (int) (rect.getHeight() - 1);
        }
        if (rect.y < 0) {
            new_y = -1;
        }
        rect.setLocation(new_x, new_y);
        return false;
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2d.setColor(Color.green);
//      g2d.fillRect(10, 10, 100, 100);

        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);

        if (firstTime) {
            rect.setLocation(x, y);
            firstTime = false;
        }
        g2d.setColor(Color.red);
//      g2d.fillRect( rect.x, rect.y, 50, 50);
        g2d.drawImage(Node_Sprite, rect.x, rect.y, 50, 50, null);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you are extending JLabel. You are not using the label to paint text or an Icon. Instead you are actually doing the custom painting yourself so you should be extending JComponent.

Or the other approach is to just use a JLabel to display the image and then create your listener to drag the label to a new location and let the label to the painting. You can check out [Component Mover](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/06/14/moving-windows/) which allows you to drag any component.